# align text left and remove padding

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm struggling to align text left and remove padding so my mini cart text is level with the variation text. Please see the image.
Thanks for the help I'm still learning

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Kf4.png)

I think this is the CSS

```
.woocommerce ul.cart_list li dl dd p:last-child, .woocommerce ul.product_list_widget li dl dd p:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0; }
```

My website [click here](https://dmcustomdesigns.co.uk)

Thanks

Comment: Generally it is considered bad practice to link to an outside code source because 1) it could be a security risk, and 2) it could change over time-- once you've fixed the issue, the question loses all value for new visitors to the post.  Instead, you should try to make a [mcve]-- preferably as an working snippet-- in the question body.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: This could also be considered bad practice but can get you out of a pinch if you need a quick fix right away. Add !important to the css value ex: margin-bottom: 0 !important;